How to change Gnome files (46.2) active tab color?
How do I reverse the active/inactive tab colors in files for the default 24.04 ubuntu theme?
The active tab is 'greyed out' while the inactive tabs are 'white'.  Dark theme reverses such that active is lighter than inactive, but the rest of dark theme is unusable for me, so that's not a viable alternative.
Possibly related aside: text edit also has grey active/white inactive.  Fortunately I could install gedit (46.2) which adds a high visibility orange underline to the active tab and use that instead.
Default Gnome terminal (3.52.0 for gnome 46) also includes the orange high visibility underline on tabs which is great.

I'm no expert in themes, so I'll suggest waiting for others who make changes far more regularly... but a neofetch tells me I'm using greybird as my current theme (running GNOME [46.2], and exploring its details I do see gtk-color-scheme = "base_color:#fcfcfc\nbg_color:#CECECE\ntooltip_bg_color:#000000\nselected_bg_color:#9db6cd\ntext_color:#000000\nfg_color:#3c3c3c\ntooltip_fg_color:#FFFFFF\nselected_fg_color:#F5F5F5\nlink_color:#74a0c6\nbg_color_dark:#686868\nfg_color_dark:#fcfcfc" so if you can't find another theme that does what you want; you could always edit the colors yourself

Please note... even I don't touch the original themes (hey we all make mistakes), so I copy the existing theme to a new variant on my system & change that one... as if I screw something up I both have the original to return to, and explore what I did that screwed it up.  (ps:  I can't recall what the original theme was for an install; this install isn't new, and I've likely changed it, so I'm using what I see as example of what I'd do)... I'd likely explore other themes first too, as colors are usually chosen for a reason...

The tool "Gradience" allows to edit colors of GTK4 apps that use the libadwaita library to theme their appearance. Likely, you will be able to change the color of the selected tab with it.
While Gradience probably will still work for the most part, development unfortunately stopped.
